# help recognizing a finite dimensional lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

Is the Lie algebra with generators $a$, $b$, $c$ and commutators
$$ [a,b]=2c, \quad [c,b]=2a, \quad [c,a]=2b $$
isomorphic to something well-known?

Comment: This is almost a presentation of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ except that the middle relation should be $[b, c] = 2a$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan $2+3=4$ except that $3$ should be replaced by $2$.

Comment: @YCor: well, I was implicitly asking if the OP intended the other presentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ (over any field of characteristic $\neq 2$).

Indeed, write $x=(c-a)/2$, $y=(c+a)/2$, $h=b$. Then $[x,y]=h$, $[h,x]=2x$, $[h,y]=-2y$, which is the standard Lie algebra law for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$.

(Of course in characteristic 2, it's abelian.)

Comment: Except that I get $[x,y]=-h$: am I making a mistake or is there a way to also fix this?

Comment: Thanks, now fixed (changing $x$ to $-x$: this does not affect $hx=2x$).

Answer (score 2):

Denote by $L$ the above Lie algebra over a  field $K$. Since $\dim L=3$ and obviously $[L,L]=L$ we already know that, for $K=\mathbb{C}$, $L\cong \mathfrak{sl}_2(K)$. For $K=\mathbb{R}$ one could compute the Killing form to see that it is not negative definite. Thus again $L\cong \mathfrak{sl}_2(K)$. But clearly, Yves answer is the best one, as we see the answer for all fields with $2\neq 0$ directly.

Comment: What I actually did was to also first observe that the Lie algebra is simple, and then to check if we have some nonzero element $h$ such that $\mathrm{ad}(x)$ is diagonalizable over the ground field (since this is enough to be isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}_2$), and in the original basis $(a,c,b)$ indeed $\mathrm{ad}(b)=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -2 & 0\\ -2 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, which is diagonalizable, and I just changed the other basis element to make it diagonal.